# How can I create a stored procedure which takes values from a table and insert them into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create a stored procedure in SQL which accepts name,area,startdate,enddate as  inputs from a table and inserts name,area and date into a table(having 3 columns name,area,date) for every date between startdate and enddate.

Comment: what do you mean by new table?

Comment: @ManojKumar . . . Functions don't modify the database state (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).  You probably intend a stored procedure, so the hint is:  `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: It is a table with 3 columns name, area and date

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot perform DDL and DML operations in functions in SQL Server.

As Gordon suggested, you need to use a stored procedure to achieve this.

Here is an example to start with

http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_stored_procedure_INSERT.php

Comment: @Darknight can you let me know how to create the sp to achieve the desired result

Comment: @DhanuKumar : check the link in answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link!.. but  the link shows just a normal insert using stored procedure, but here i need to insert a record for every date between startdate and enddate

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(20) = 'name';
DECLARE @area NVARCHAR(20) = 'area';
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2016-11-30';
DECLARE @endDate DATE = '2016-12-30';

DECLARE @currentDate DATE = @startDate;

SELECT
    @currentDate AS Date
INTO
    #dates;

WHILE(@currentDate < @endDate)
    BEGIN
        SET @currentDate = DATEADD(d, 1, @currentDate);
        INSERT INTO #dates
        VALUES( @currentDate);
    END;

SELECT
    @name,
    @area,
    *
FROM
    #dates;
```

You can get variables as parameter and use the last select statement to create your new table.